# Query MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, select

I have a table fingerprint in mysql 5.7 like this :

[image]

Now, I want to select data like this :

[image]

So what query can I use? Please Help Me

Comment: with
a as (
  select pin, tanggal, jab_absen,
  row_number() over(partition by pin order by jam_absen) as rn
),
b as (
  select *,
    rn / 2 as line,
    rn % 2 as side
  from a
),
select
  l.pin,
  l.tanggal,
  l.jab_absen as h_in,
  r.jab_absen as h_out
from b l
left join b r on r.line = l.line and r.side = 0
where l.side = 1
order by l.line

Comment: @TheImpaler, can use in mysql 5.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that in and out records are consistently interleaved in the table, then one option is `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    pin, 
    tangaal_absen,
    max(case when rn % 2 = 1 then jam_absen end) jam_absen_in,
    max(case when rn % 2 = 0 then jam_absen end) jam_absen_out
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by pin, tangaal_absen order by jam_absen) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by pin, tangaal_absen, floor((rn - 1) / 2)
```

Comment: i get error in mysql 5.7 : "> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by pin, tanggal_absen order by jam_absen) as rn
      from tb_log t
  )' at line 9", I have to update mysql or is there another query that can be used in mysql 5.7?

Comment: @risq: this requires MySQL 8.0. Writing the same query ni MySQL 5.7 is quite  challenging...

Comment: so what kind of query can be used in MySQL 5.7? Sorry I am still confused and please help me